# How do I increase scroll speed in Microsoft Edge in Ubuntu

Tags: browser, scrolling, microsoft

It's really bothering me, it scrolls really slow. I'm new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Slow scrolling is not something I've seen with Edge on Ubuntu, but you can look at some of the scroll settings like this:

From Edge:

1. Paste `edge://flags/` into the address bar
2. Search "scroll"

This will show you everything related to scrolling that you can do in Edge. You'll need to try changing different options to see which ones will improve scrolling on your system, though "Smooth Scrolling" and "Enable Lazy Image Loading" would be good places to start. Some of these are not 100% supported in Linux just yet, though there is *some* support when the options are changed.

Hope this gives you something to work with.

Comment: I turned on smooth scrolling, not fast but not rouge and uncomfortable like before